# How to get method which got attribute and

Tags: c#, methods, attributes

Hello I need two things.
I saw somewhere something like this

You have a method where you put [Attribute] above and the code adds every method names as string in the list, dictionary whatever. I need it because I want to make network system with RPC and want to check (and define method as function call over the network) on the server and client if same RPC names exists.. if not exists then print error.

Well I found few things like System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); and   MethodInfo[] methods but I don't know how to continue / use it. Very Important. I need to know params too.

As test I made this small thing.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class Navigation : Attribute
{

}

public class MenuNavigator
{
    [Navigation]
    void Next()
    {

    }

    [Navigation]
    void Last(bool bla)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking,  are you trying to get all method names and parameters for methods that have a particular attribute?

Comment: Yea I want to get all method names which can have random names. So I cannot make GetMethod("blabla"). So I need to loop it or something and check if it has [Navigation] attribute

Comment: Use [Type.GetMethods() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx) to get al the available methods in a `type`. Then use [CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<T>() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292.aspx) to check if a method is decorated with a custom attribute. And use [MethodBase.GetParameters() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) to get the available parameters for a method.

Comment: Oh, and be sure to use the proper [BindingFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) in `GetMethods()`. Since you use a private methods in your example, you might need to set the `BindingFlags.NonPublic` flag.

Comment: Thanks. Privates had still problem. Since I add BindingFlags.Instance it helped. But I have still problem. So far I "generate" this code (which looks like network code): http://pastebin.com/e51Z5wgj  If I have child class but I use the parent class typof(Parent) it doesn't work. But with the child I haven't problem. That is my last problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Add that code from pastebin to here

Comment: @MaZy Your code in Pastebin works as it should... AFAIK, you can't query a *non existing* methods from a `type`.  But if you're going for abstraction maybe something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vcPL5

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're asking how to use reflection to see whether a method has a specific attribute or not, you do it like this.

```
void Main()
{
    MenuNavigator navigator = new MenuNavigator();

    Navigation methodNextAttribute = navigator.GetType()
                                              .GetMethod("Next")
                                              .GetCustomAttribute<Navigation>();

    Console.WriteLine ("Method `Next` has the `Navigation` attribute?\n> {0}\n", methodNextAttribute != null);
    // -------- Output -------- 
    // Method `Next` has the `Navigation` attribute?
    // > True

    Navigation methodLastAttribute = navigator.GetType()
                                              .GetMethod("Last")
                                              .GetCustomAttribute<Navigation>();

    Console.WriteLine ("Method `Last` has the `Navigation` attribute?\n > {0}\n", methodLastAttribute != null);  
    // -------- Output -------- 
    // Method `Last` has the `Navigation` attribute?
    // > False

}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class Navigation : Attribute
{
}

public class MenuNavigator
{
    [Navigation]
    public void Next()
    {
    }

    public void Last(bool bla)
    {
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

In response to the comment you made under your original question...

```
void Main()
{
    ControlCharacter control = new ControlCharacter();
    control.GetType()
           .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
           .Where(method => method.GetCustomAttribute<RPC>() == null)
           .Select(method => method.Name)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class RPC : Attribute
{
}

public class NetworkBehavior
{
}

public class ControlCharacter : NetworkBehavior
{
    [RPC] 
    public void Move() { }

    public void DrawHud() { }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. Something like this was what I had first but the problem is I cannot use GetMethod("Name") because the method name can be random example if customer want to define own method with other parameters.  Thats why I wanted add attribute to make it easier for the future *edit*

Comment: So do you want to retrieve all the method names?

Comment: yes but @IronGeek and you gave me good tips and I got it work. Only one problem I got which I did write down and my written code so far via pastepin link (look above comments) :).

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because `NetworkBehaviour` does not have any methods defined. The class `ControlCharacter`that derives from `NetworkBehaviour` inherits members of `NetworkBehaviour`, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response but I went other way. You helped me a lot. I am going  through all methods which I can find from the assembly. Then I check for RPC definition. That will include even the NetworkBehaviour baseclass.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// Currently it supports up to 255 RPCs
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class RPC : Attribute
{
    static byte rpcIdCounter = 0;
    //maybe channels
    public byte RpcId { get; private set; }

    public RPC()
    {
        RpcId = rpcIdCounter++;
    }
}

public class NetworkBehaviour
{

    // later network functions
    [RPC] //remote proceure call
    protected void Base()  //example remote call on other computer Move()
    {
    }

    [RPC]
    protected virtual void OverridableBase()
    {
    }

    protected virtual void OverridableNotRPC()
    {
    }
}

class ControlCharacter : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [RPC] //remote proceure call
    void Move()  //example remote call on other computer Move()
    {

    }

    public void DrawHud() // example this will not do remote call
    {

    }
}

class OtherClass : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [RPC]
    void Start()
    {
    }

    [RPC]
    void Stop()
    {
    }

    protected override void OverridableBase()
    {
    }

    [RPC]
    protected override void OverridableNotRPC()
    {
    }

    void NotRPC()
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("ControlCharacter ---");
        //var obj = new ControlCharacter();

        //foreach(var m in GetRPCMethods(obj)) {
        //    Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
        //}

        //Console.WriteLine("OtherClass ---");

        //var other = new OtherClass();
        //foreach(var m in GetRPCMethods(other)) {
        //    Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
        //}

        //Console.WriteLine("NetworkBehaviour ---");
        //var next = (typeof(NetworkBehaviour));
        //foreach(var m in next.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where(e => e.GetCustomAttribute<RPC>() != null)) {
        //    Console.WriteLine("NetworkBehaviour: " + m.ToString());
        //}
        //Console.WriteLine("");

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var Types = assembly.GetTypes();

        var names = (from type in Types
                     from method in type.GetMethods( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance ).Where(e => e.GetCustomAttribute<RPC>() != null)
                     select type.FullName + ":" + method.Name).ToList();

        foreach(var methodNames in names) {
            Console.WriteLine(methodNames);
        }


    }

    //public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetRPCMethods(NetworkBehaviour obj)
    //{
    //    return obj.GetType()
    //        // Remove BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly to include method from base class      
    //              .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(e => e.GetCustomAttribute<RPC>() != null);
    //}
}
```

Output:

```
NetworkBehaviour:Base
NetworkBehaviour:OverridableBase
ControlCharacter:Move
ControlCharacter:Base
ControlCharacter:OverridableBase
OtherClass:Start
OtherClass:Stop
OtherClass:OverridableBase
OtherClass:OverridableNotRPC
OtherClass:Base
```